Unity Debug - find out which exposed GameObject variable a certain GameObject in the scene is attached to?
Unity Debug - (when you're jumping into someone's convoluted sourcebase)
Is there a way to automatically(?) find out which exposed GameObject variable a certain GameObject in the scene is attached to?

Are you looking for something like this? / Like this?
